# C# Reflection: Emit DateTime Property Value

Tags: c#, datetime, reflection.emit

I am currently working with generating dynamic types using Reflection.Emit.

I have the majority of what I need working however need to set default property values in the constructor.

I have so far got this working for Integers and Strings by using for example (reduced for brevity):

`ctorDefaultIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello World");`

`ctorDefaultIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 42);`

This works perfectly, my question is how would I go about setting a DateTime value.

Comment: Emit a call to the constructor.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer. Then mark it as the solution :) You found the answer, you deserve the rep :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @leppie for future ref here's the code I ended up using. 
For some context this is being passed into another method:

```
ctorDefaultIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I8, dateVal.Ticks);
ctorDefaultIL.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, 
  typeof(DateTime).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(long) }));
```